# How to vertical align a select with a JQuery button?

Tags: css

I'm sure there's an easy solution for this, but so far I've not found it and I'm about ready to throw my PC through the window.

Any ideas how I can vertical align a select with a jQuery button where the button height is greater than the height of the select.  Like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/hCCzQ/4/

I'm trying to align them so that the select is in the middle of the button.

Many thanks!

Comment: Please always include your source code in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me well:

```
select, button {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/hCCzQ/6/

Comment: Excellent, thanks very much!  The simple solution is always the best.  I've literally been looking at this for hours with nested divs coming out of my ears.

Comment: @MartinBurrow Yes, the simplest solution feeds on the time :) You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/5FL4a/

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

  var b = $("#abutton");
  var s = $('select');   

  $(b, s).css('vertical-align', 'middle');
 });
```

---

**Using classes with CSS styles from @jnylen post:**

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var b = $("#abutton");
    var s = $('select');   

    b.addClass('btn');
    s.addClass('ddl');
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.btn {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 40px;
    width: 32px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.ddl {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}​
```

​

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way I could find to get it pixel-perfect:

```
button {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 40px;
    width: 32px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

select {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hCCzQ/12/

It looks pretty good in Firefox and IE7.